# Unable to read data from Map of Primitive data type from Cassandra DB using Scala

Tags: java, scala, cassandra, key-value-store, typetoken

Need help in reading data from Cassandra DB of type Map(varchar,double) in Scala.

i am using Cassandra core 3.0 and data is stored in DB by third party API so i cannot change type

I was trying to read using row.getMap("column_name", classOf[String], classOf[Double])) but i am facing following error: "IllegalArgumentException: Primitive type 'double' used as type parameter"

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Could you clarify what library/driver (including version) do you use to access Cassandra?

Comment: I am using cassandra-driver-core-3.3.2.jar

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe that the reason of the issue is that [`getMap`](http://docs.datastax.com/en/drivers/java/3.1/com/datastax/driver/core/AbstractGettableData.html#getMap-java.lang.String-java.lang.Class-java.lang.Class-) returns `java.util.Map` and standard Java collections do not support value types (aka primitive types) as generic keys or values. Wrapper objects are used instead such as [`java.lang.Double`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Double.html) (see also [autoboxing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/autoboxing.html)). So try something like

```
row.getMap("column_name", classOf[String], classOf[java.lang.Double]))
```

Comment: @priyankagoel, if it works - mark it as an Accepted Answer ;-)